# How to get all the values of a third dimensions array in another array

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

so I was trying to get all the "videos" arrays, saved in another array with a loop, with no luck, do you know a better way to achieve this?

[image: So this is the structure of the graph query]

And this is the loop I was trying to achieve, but in the last loop, I think there is something wrong, I'm only getting the first 2 videos saved only.

````
   returnArrayVideos() {


      let array = [];
      for (let gallery = 0; gallery < this.videos.length; gallery++) {
     
         for(let i=0; i < this.videos[gallery].submitVideos.length; i++){
         
          for(let a=0; a < this.videos[i].submitVideos[i].length; a++){
              
              array[a] = this.videos[a].submitVideos[a];
             

          }
      }
      }
      return array;
    }

    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that `this.videos` in your code refers to `data.allVideoGalleries`, you can get all video objects in a flat array as follows:

```js
returnArrayVideos() {
  return this.videos.map(v => v.submitVideos).flat()
}
```

Comment: This is my new favorite function, amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const videos = data.allVideoGalleries.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur.submitVideos], []);
```